# Why is Gnu grep exit status always 0 on standard input?

Tags: bash, grep, exit-code

On a bash command line in Ubuntu 14.04 :

```
echo "z" | grep -e 'x' ; echo $PIPESTATUS
```

always displays 0, even though, obviously, there's no "x" in "z".  But:

```
echo "z" > /tmp/z
grep -e 'x' /tmp/z ; echo $PIPESTATUS
```

works as I expect, returning 1 if the pattern is 'x' (as shown), and 0 if the pattern is 'z'.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PIPESTATUS` is actually a BASH array variable containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline.

To print all the exit statuses, you need to use it as:

```
echo "z" | grep -e 'x' ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 1
```

Where `0` is exit status of first `echo` command and `1` is the exit status of grep command.

When you use `echo $PIPESTATUS` it just prints **first element** of array.

To check the `grep` command status you don't even need to use `PIPESTATUS`.

You should just use `$?`:

```
echo "z" | grep -q 'x' ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Yes. With bash arrays, `$ary` is actually `${ary[0]}`

Comment: Yes, this is a big "Aha!" for me.  Thanks.